# How to return/print a method of multiple objects in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, class, methods, return

Im quite new to Java and Im wondering if I could output the distance between my Hero and every City at once? How could the method I look for look like?

```
City city = new City();
City city1 = new City();
City city2 = new City();
City city3 = new City();
System.out.println(city.distance(hero)); // works fine for a single city = 21.1 something
System.out.println(City.noOfCitys); // works fine = 4
System.out.println(City.distances(hero)); // should output all distances at once for example as string
```

My City Class already counting the created objects with static noOfCitys

```
package adventure;

public class City {
    
    static int noOfCitys = 0; 
    { 
        noOfCitys += 1; 
    } 
    
    private String name = "Stadt";
    private int posX = 15;
    private int posY = 15;
    
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPosX(){
        return this.posX;
    }
    
    public void setPosX(int posX){
        this.posX = posX;
    }
    
    public int getPosY(){
        return this.posY;
    }
    
    public void setPosY(int posY){
        this.posY = posY;
    }
    
    
    public String distance(Adventurer hero) {
        return ""+Math.sqrt(((this.posX-hero.getX())*(this.posX-hero.getX()))+((this.posY-hero.getY())*(this.posY-hero.getY())));
    }
}
```

Additional info: I already looked into several answers to similar like question but did not have the clue  how to append to my particular question.

Comment: Create your new distances method and return a String[] (String Array) that you have filled with the distances. Then you can just step through the array where you want to work with it and have every distance.

Comment: Ill have a look into it later. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @funky(I adapted it a bit) worked like a charm.
Thank you.

```
        City[] city = new City[3];
        Hero hero = new Hero();
        
        city[0] = new City("Men-nefer",290,165);
        city[1] = new City("Heliopolis",262,170);
        city[2] = new City("Merimda",250,130);
        
        System.out.println(city[0].distance(hero));
        System.out.println(city[1].distance(hero));
        System.out.println(city[2].distance(hero));
```